# Screen Tearing on Ubuntu 20.04 with XPS15 (9500)

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, dell, xps, tearing

This is what I see when I run a [screen tearing test video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfL_JkcEFbE):

[image: Screen Tearing Test]

I am running `NVIDIA` driver version **460.32.03** and the `XPS15` contains the graphics processor **GeForce GTX 1650 Ti**.

I have already tried:

- Switching the driver from version **460** to **450**
- Save an X Configuration file with nvidia-settings and add the
  following params to the Screen Section: `Option "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"`

**Info**: I can't select FullCompositionPipeline in the nvidia-settings GUI like some solution approaches suggest, because it is not there, even if I select `Advanced...` see screenshot:
[image]

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 3):

The following solution worked for me.

Create this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-drm-nomodeset.conf
```

Add the following line to it: `options nvidia-drm modeset=1`

Save the file and then run this command in the terminal:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

And reboot.

Source: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/07/fix-screen-tearing-ubuntu-18-04-optimus-laptops/

Additional Info: https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/470.57.02/README/kms.html

**EDIT**: Upgrade to the newest Nvidia driver `470`, it will also bring some improvements. With the above solution screen tearing disappeared to about 95% in my case, but here and there it was still present, but now I have the feeling it is completely gone.